# How do PC sound cards cope with headsets of different impedance?

Tags: audio, impedance, computers

I recently got a PC motherboard that advertises a "smart" audio amplifier chip to manage headsets with different impedance:

[image]

However, I have never had a problem with headphones before.

Will I notice a big change in quality when I use the new motherboard? How did older motherboards without this capability deal with differences in impedance?

Comment: Doesn't that just mean the output impedance of the motherboards amplifier is very low? Aka, it acts like variable voltage source so regardless of the headphone impedance, it will always be able to supply the correct current. For the most part, I suspect this marketing is blowing smoke up your ***.

Comment: Why do people write questions like this without actually linking to the product so it can be answered :|

Comment: A lot of these chips (this case is Realtek ALC 1220) do auto-detection to see if they have a headphone or a microphone, by passing a small DC probe current and seeing what the impedance is.

Comment: @ThePhoton They used to. My old AKGs are 600 ohms. The newer versions of the same model are 55 ohms. I think most manufacturers have followed.

Comment: @pipe, okay, that's me not knowing much about audio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maxim makes combined codec+amp chips that have this impedance detection feature built-in.

From the [MAX9856](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX9856.pdf) datasheet:

> Comprehensive load impedance
>   sensing allows the MAX9856 to autodetect
>   most common audio and audio/video headset and jack
>   plug types

Then, later:

> HPL, HPR, and JACKSNS provide a headset detection
>   feature which can both detect the insertion of a jack
>   and measure the load impedance.

It later explains in a bit more details the process they use to guess the impedance. Basically, they inject current in a way they hope won't be audible, and check the resulting voltage.

Anyway, even later in the datasheet is described the result you can actually get from this testing in some given register:

```
BITS | LOAD
00   | 200Ω < load < open
01   | 50Ω < load < 200Ω
10   | 0 < load < 50Ω
11   | Idle state
```

So you indeed get three specific relevant cases, just like in your advertisement.

I therefore suspect the motherboard just uses this chip (which, frankly, doesn't seem to have amazing performances other than that), or a similar one, and makes a big marketing deal out of it. The designers certainly didn't design some complex, specific circuitry to solve this problem.

But anyway, as JRE said, knowing the impedance of the connected load **isn't actually a problem**. The only consequence is that the power consumed by the headphones will be different depending on the impedance, so the sound will just seem louder or quieter (and this depends a lot on other factors too, like the efficiency of the speakers). The user will adjust the volume accordingly. This is not supposed to have any significant effect on sound quality anyway, except if you start to saturate the amp output.

So the only advantage this thing could really have is to eventually avoid regularily changing the volume if you use multiple kind of headphones and switching them constantly.

Answer (score 3):

The sound cards deal with impedance differences by ignoring it.  It sounds a little different, and if it sounds bad enough the user will adjust the volume or the equalizer to make it sound more acceptable.

I can't tell you tell you how your [Gigabyte Aorus sound card](https://www.gigabyte.com/mb/aorus/audio) works.  All I can find is advertising jibberish.

---

If I were to make a guess, I'd say they might have some kind if feedback that allows the amplifier to automatically apply equalization to the output in order to compensate for the changes in volume and frequency response the result from a impedance mismatch.

Exactly how they do that I can't say.  I know how I would try to do it, but I'm no engineer.  The way I would go at would probably be too expensive and complicated (and not work well enough) for a commercial product.  And I probably wouldn't bother.  It'd be more work to get the automatic watchamacallit to work than to just use the correct headphone and/or adjust the equalizer and volume.